# PDO SQL won't add new entries

Tags: php, sql, pdo, insert

No error is showing, but for some reason I cannot add new entries when I run this script. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO inventory(sku, product-id, product-id-type, price, minimum-seller-allowed-price, maximum-seller-allowed-price, item-condition, quantity, add-delete, will-ship-internationally, expedited-shipping, item-note, fulfillment-center-id)
VALUES(:sku, :product_id, :product_id_type, :price, :minimum, :maximum, :condition, :quantity, :add_delete, :international, :expedited, :note, :fulfillment)');
$sth->bindParam(':sku', $sku);
$sth->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id);
$sth->bindParam(':product_id_type', $product_id_type);
$sth->bindParam(':price', $price);
$sth->bindParam(':minimum', $minimum);
$sth->bindParam(':maximum', $maximum);
$sth->bindParam(':condition', $condition);
$sth->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
$sth->bindParam(':add_delete', $add_delete);
$sth->bindParam(':international', $international);
$sth->bindParam(':expedited', $expedited);
$sth->bindParam(':note', $note);
$sth->bindParam(':fulfillment', $fulfillment);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: You're not checking your calls to `PDO` for errors, so if there are any you won't see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"No error is showing..."*

No errors? Because, you're not checking for them. Many of your columns contain hyphens and MySQL thinks you want to do math.

I.e.: `product-id` which MySQL translates as "product **minus** id" etc.

`setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`
would have signaled the syntax errors.

Wrap all your columns that contains hyphens with ticks.

```
(sku, `product-id`, `product-id-type` ...
```

etc.

- Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

---

Nota:

- You should try and avoid using hyphens as word seperators and use underscores instead.
  That way you won't have to use ticks.

Comment: Or you could *always* use ticks ;-)

Comment: *Hm....*, "to tick or not to tick"? What would William have done, had he been a coder *Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Methinks I couldn't even guess @Fred -ii- *Mornin' Ralph!*

Comment: Me thinks he'd tick, if he had a dawg; *Mornin' Sam!* - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

Added here because i can't code it properly in a comment. This is not an answer to the question but i suspect will lead directly to it.

Alter your code like this.

```
try { 
    // All $sth lines above in this section.

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // this will print an exception out if there is one.
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```